# Can anyone de-obfuscate this exploit?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, antivirus, exploit, malware

I came across the following exploit due to a warning from my AV software. It originated from an adserver delivering banner ads on one of my sites.

I have retrieved the content with Wget and copied to pastebin.

http://pastebin.com/m6fa38fac
**[Warning: Link may contain malware - Do not visit from vulnerable PC.]**

Please note that you have to scroll horizontally on pastebin as the code is all on one line.

Can anyone find out what the exploit actually does?

Thank you.

Comment: Make sure your AV is up and running as I just visited pastebin and got the alert again.

Comment: name the variables some normal name, then decode characters as ASCII, not that big problem. asking someone else to do the work, that's just too much.

Comment: I think you should probably consider extracting the text and providing in a textual form to protect other people from problems.

Comment: @dusoft If I was aware of how to do it, you would not be reading this right now.

Comment: @Simon P Stevens I think the anti-virus software gives you the alert anyhow, even though the code does not actually execute. As long as the AV finds a certain string and it matches its AV malware list, then the alert will be triggered including clear text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite, as it includes (the equivalent of):

```
var mtime= new Date(document.lastModified).toUTCString().split(' ')[4].split(':');
```

it then uses the minutes and seconds of the last-modified time of the document containing it as a key to decode the array. If you can't still retrieve that `javascript:alert(document.lastModified)` time we'd have to brute-force it.

ETA: ah, actually it only uses the first digit of the minutes, and from the way it uses it we can guess it's supposed to be `1`. That's leaves only sixty possibilities, and a quick loop reveals that meaningful javascript only comes out for `16` seconds.

I've put the decoded script [here](http://pastebin.com/m7eec84b0); it will probably also ping your anti-virus. Summary: it runs exploits against the Java, Flash and Acrobat plugins, running a payload from googleservice.net which is (surprise surprise) a Russian attack site.

Comment: Is there some kind of tool or library that could be used to parse it first and then simply output the resulting code?

Comment: @mr-euro: please break the URL in this comment and the other one eg. by losing the http. In comments, URLs are auto-linked, and unlike the pastebin link this really is a link to a live exploit!

Comment: So is this really only affecting people with obsolete versions of Java, Acrobat and Flash plugins? All browsers too?

Comment: Correct, the URI revealed in the AV software in question is exactly: googleservice.net/info/news.php (usually with some GUID as the query string).

Comment: Yes. Plugins are the #1 exploit target at the moment: browsers typically check themselves for updates, plugins less so, so they're very often out of date. Acrobat is a particularly bad offender because people don't realise they're getting a plug-in when they install a PDF reader application. Note that the exploits served from these sites often depend on the User-Agent string passed in; if you'd downloaded that script from IE you might have got different results.

Answer (score 3):

This ussualy works to print de-obfuscated code

```
eval = alert;
```

in firefox with firebug, i solved it like this:

```
var lpsy16=lpsy;
eval = console.log; // This line was added
eval(lpsy+parseInt(gouy[0]));
```

Output is here:
--deleted due to zoidberg's comment--

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to actually do that? Where would that be inserted?

Comment: I wouldn't post the URL, last thing we want is google spiders picking up Stackoverflow linking to exploit sites!